# i am not able to create the last table in my database,Help?

Tags: mysql, table

```
CREATE DATABASE DIVIGN;

USE DIVIGN;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER  
(CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,  
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (32),  
LAST_NAME VARCHAR (32),  
PASSWORD VARCHAR (16),  
ADDRESS VARCHAR  (100),  
COUNTRY VARCHAR (32),  
AGE INTEGER (3),  
GENDER CHAR (1),  
EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR  (32),  
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(10));  

CREATE TABLE SELLER
(SELLER_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,  
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (32),  
LAST_NAME VARCHAR (32),  
PASSWORD VARCHAR (16),  
ADDRESS VARCHAR (100),   
COUNTRY VARCHAR (32),  
EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR  (32),  
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR (10)

);  

CREATE TABLE ARTWORK
(ARTWORK_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,  
SELLER_ID INTEGER (10),  
NAME VARCHAR (32),  
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (120),  
CATEGORY VARCHAR (32),
PRICE INTEGER (10),  
QUANTITY_AVAILABLE INTEGER (10),  
KEYWORDS VARCHAR (100),  
CONSTRAINT FK_SiD FOREIGN KEY (SELLER_ID) REFERENCES SELLER (SELLER_ID)  
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS  
(ORDER_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,  
CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER (10),  
ORDER_DATE DATE,  
PAYPAL_ADDRESS VARCHAR (10),  
SHIPPING_ADDRESS VARCHAR (100),  
SHIPPING_COUNTRY VARCHAR (32),  
SHIPPED_DATE DATE,  
COMPLETED VARCHAR (16),  
CONSTRAINT FK_CiD FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID)  
);                      


CONSTRAINT FK_AiD FOREIGN KEY (ARTWORK_ID) REFERENCES ARTWORK (ARTWORK_ID)  
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL  
(ORDER_ID INTEGER (10),  
ARTWORK_ID INTEGER (10),  
SELLER_ID INTEGER (10),  
PRICE INTEGER (10),  
QUANTITY INTEGER (10),  
CONSTRAINT FK_OiD FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_ID)    
CONSTRAINT FK_AiD FOREIGN KEY (ARTWORK_ID) REFERENCES ARTWORK (ARTWORK_ID)    
CONSTRAINT FK_SiD FOREIGN KEY (SELLER_ID) REFERENCES SELLER (SELLER_ID)     
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a foreign key created for `SELLER_ID` on the table `ARTWORK`, you will need to rename it to something like `CONSTRAINT FK_SiD_Order FOREIGN KEY (SELLER_ID) REFERENCES SELLER (SELLER_ID)`

If the line `CONSTRAINT FK_AiD FOREIGN KEY (ARTWORK_ID) REFERENCES ARTWORK (ARTWORK_ID)` above the `CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL` is removed, the code should work fine.

Also a `,` is missing in the last table syntax. So the code for the last table should be

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL
(ORDER_ID INTEGER (10),
ARTWORK_ID INTEGER (10),
SELLER_ID INTEGER (10),
PRICE INTEGER (10),
QUANTITY INTEGER (10),
CONSTRAINT FK_OiD FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_AiD FOREIGN KEY (ARTWORK_ID) REFERENCES ARTWORK (ARTWORK_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_SiD_Order FOREIGN KEY (SELLER_ID) REFERENCES SELLER (SELLER_ID)
);
```

The code you posted is not easily readable, use the code tags appropriately and include any error messages.